# an object reference is required for nonstatic field or method. (web services)

Tags: web-services, web-applications, object, reference

I'm having trouble with using a function for a website application that takes the url of an xml file and the url of it's corresponding xsd file and validates the xml file against the xsd.

Although the web method worked when i tested it on my 2 files, when programming the functionality of the button i get (an object reference is required for nonstatic field or method.)

If i try to make the verification method static, then it doesn't show up for use in my web app, and it doesn't show up when i test the web services.

If I need to create an instance of an object, im not quite sure how to do that properly. Any help is appreciated, i wasn't able to figure it out from questions regarding the similar problem.

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string x = TextBox1.Text;
            string y = TextBox2.Text;
            DevyoWebAapp.localhost.WebService.verification(x, y);
        }

```
[WebMethod]  
public string verification(string x, string y)  
{  
    // Create the XmlSchemaSet class.  
    XmlSchemaSet sc = new XmlSchemaSet();  
    // Add the schema to the collection before performing validation  
    sc.Add(x, y);   
    // Define the validation settings.  
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();  
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;  
    settings.Schemas = sc; // Association
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
    // Create the XmlReader object.
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(x, settings);
    // Parse the file. 
    while (reader.Read()) ; // will call event handler if invalid
    return ("The XML file validation has completed");
}
// Display any validation errors.
private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Validation Error: {0}", e.Message);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think its referring to the service, try it like this:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string x = TextBox1.Text;
    string y = TextBox2.Text;

    var service = new DevyoWebAapp.localhost.WebService();
    service.verification(x, y);
}
```